# R Shiny include button that collapses one part and expands another part of a panel

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am looking to expand the functionality of a button I have in my R shiny dashboard which can now collapse or expand a part of the menu. Currently I use the following type of button

`HTML('<button class="inline" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Collapse Menu</button>')`

Where the #demo part of the menu is collapsed / expanded on click. I would like to also collapse another menu when clicking on the button (specifically, I want to collapse #demo and expand another id, say #example, and vice-versa).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the library shinyjs. The function toggle, given an ID, does what you need I think.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton(inputId = "go",label = "Button"),
  div(id="div_a","Hello There",style="background-color:red;"),
  div(id="div_b","General Kenobi",style="background-color:green;")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  hide(id = "div_b")
  
  observeEvent(input$go,{
    toggle(id = "div_a",anim = T)
    toggle(id = "div_b",anim = T)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```